Is it a copyright violation to copy a website's text into Google Translate?
Is entering the text of a website into Google Translate considered a copyright violation, assuming the only purpose is to understand the text?

Worth noting that Google does translate entire websites as a matter of course, with a prompt asking if you want to translate it, and that translations of entire works are per se derivative works. So, Google might be infringing copyright by doing so. Part of the legal theoretical/analytical issue is whether the infringing derivative work is authored by the person using Google translate or Google itself.

Depends
While it is an unauthorised copy, not all unauthorised copying is copyright infringement. The copyright law in each jurisdiction is different on what sort of copying is a violation and what is ok.
